# Unknown plant growing in indoor kale garden

Tags: identification, plant-care, kale, volunteer

A plant has consistently grown in an indoor kale garden next to the kale as shown in the image below.

What is this plant?
Even if the plant is unknown, is there a way to determine if such a plant is beneficial in any way to the growth of the kale plants?

[image]

Answer (score -1):

**I wouldn't taste or eat it without knowing where it came from.**

I would take a `lower leaf`, *crush it up* and *check the fragrance*. It looks a bit like `basil`, maybe `spinach`.

Do you have more recent pictures?
Have you grown anything in the past that may have seeded in the soil?

Comment: The plant hasn't grown significantly since the last picture. No, I've not grown any other plant in the past with the soil.